# Can't pull data from Dart Flutter FireBase

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();

FirebaseFirestore FS = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

CollectionReference TC = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("oneSignal");
var docs = TC.doc("xcG9kfCWnUK7QKbK37qd");
var response = await docs.get();

var veriable = response.data();

print(veriable);
```

I am trying to pull data from FireBase FireStore with this code. But I am getting an error like this:

[image]

---

Rule codes:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /oneSignal/{signalId} {
        allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `allow read` to the rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /oneSignal/{signalId} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code you provided solved the problem. Thank you so much.